# How to show this is an embedding from ${\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})}$?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, projective-geometry, projective-space

I know intuitively that the mapping given by
$$
p : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \{[(x,y,1)]\ |\ x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}\subset \mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R}), p((x,y)) = [(x,y,1)]
$$
will be an embedding from ${\mathbb{R}^2}$ to ${\{[(x,y,1)]\ |\ x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}\subset \mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})}$. But how would I show it formally? It's clearly bijective, but I need to show continuity of $p$ and it's inverse, which involves looking at the open subsets of ${\{[(x,y,1)]\ |\ x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}}$, for which I am a bit stuck

Comment: Perhaps the answerer has a "point"!

Comment: @amWhy is that a clue?

Comment: Maybe a "point", maybe a "carrot".

Comment: You can use the fact that $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is a quotient of $\mathbb R^3-\{0\}.$ In particular, a set in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is open if and only if its preimage in $\mathbb R^3$ is open.